# Asynchronous WCF calls throws ServiceModel.ActionNotSupportedException

Tags: asynchronous, wcf

I am writing a WCF client that reads a firmware file, copies it to byte array sends it to the WCF server. The server flashes it to another device connected to it. Both the server and the client are written by me.

I have created a WCF service inline in code without using the service model configuration section in the configuration.xml. Since the server might take a minute to flash, I have implemented the contract as asynchronous so that the client need not wait till the flashing is complete. Both server and client share the same IFirmwareUpgrade interface.

Howver when I run the client and the server, am getting the ServiceModel.ActionNotSupportedException exception. Here is the exception details.

```
The message with Action 'ServiceContractNS/UpdatorContract/UpgradeFirmware' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
```

Here is the Server code

```
namespace Updator
   {
    partial class UpdatorWCFService : IUpdator, IFirmwareUpgrade
    {
        public bool UpgradeFirmware(string deviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer)
        {
            m_RFM220Manager.UpgradeFirmware(deviceIPAddress, buffer);
            return true;
        }

        public System.IAsyncResult BeginUpgradeFirmware(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BeginServiceAsyncMethod called with: \"{0}\"", DeviceIPAddress);
            //Do something
            return new CompletedAsyncResult<bool>(true);            
        }

        public bool EndUpgradeFirmware(System.IAsyncResult r)
        {
            CompletedAsyncResult<bool> result = r as CompletedAsyncResult<bool>;
            Console.WriteLine("EndServiceAsyncMethod called with: \"{0}\"", result.Data);
            //return result.Data;
            return false;
        }       
    }

    // Simple async result implementation.
    class CompletedAsyncResult<T> : IAsyncResult
    {
        T data;

        public CompletedAsyncResult(T data)
        { this.data = data; }

        public T Data
        { get { return data; } }

        #region IAsyncResult Members
        public object AsyncState
        { get { return (object)data; } }

        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        { get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); } }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously
        { get { return true; } }

        public bool IsCompleted
        { get { return true; } }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is how created the service

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.MaxConnections = (int)m_Configuration.wcftcpchannel.maxconnection;
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = binding.MaxBufferSize;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

// Step 3 of the hosting procedure: Add a service endpoint.
m_UITCPHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IUpdator),
    binding,
    "UpdatorWCFService");            

// Step 5 of the hosting procedure: Start (and then stop) the service.
m_UITCPHost.Open(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, m_Configuration.wcftcpchannel.timeoutinms));
```

Here is the contract

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "UpdatorContract", Namespace = "ServiceContractNS", ConfigurationName = "UpdatorContract")]
    public interface IFirmwareUpgrade
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool UpgradeFirmware(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer);

        //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true, Action = "ServiceContractNS/UpdatorContract/UpgradeFirmware", ReplyAction = "ServiceContractNS/UpdatorContract/UpgradeFirmwareResponse")]
        [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
        System.IAsyncResult BeginUpgradeFirmware(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

        // Note: There is no OperationContractAttribute for the end method.
        bool EndUpgradeFirmware(System.IAsyncResult result);
    }
```

This is the configsection in the client

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_UpdatorContract" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
            maxBufferPoolSize="20971520" maxBufferSize="20971520" maxConnections="10"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.158.96.120:8000/Updator/UpdatorWCFService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_UpdatorContract"
          contract="UpdatorContract" name="NetTcpBinding_UpdatorContract" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is the Client class for Asynchronous implementation

```
public class FirmwareUpgradeClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IFirmwareUpgrade>, IFirmwareUpgrade
    {
        private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginUpgradeFirmwareDelegate;

        private EndOperationDelegate onEndUpgradeFirmwareDelegate;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onUpgradeFirmwareCompletedDelegate;

        public event System.EventHandler<UpgradeFirmwareCompletedEventArgs> UpgradeFirmwareCompleted;

        public bool UpgradeFirmware(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer)
        {
            return base.Channel.UpgradeFirmware(DeviceIPAddress, buffer);
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public System.IAsyncResult BeginUpgradeFirmware(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
        {
            return base.Channel.BeginUpgradeFirmware(DeviceIPAddress, buffer, callback, asyncState);
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public bool EndUpgradeFirmware(System.IAsyncResult result)
        {
            return base.Channel.EndUpgradeFirmware(result);
        }

        private System.IAsyncResult OnBeginUpgradeFirmware(object[] inValues, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
        {
            string DeviceIPAddress = ((string)(inValues[0]));
            byte[] buffer = ((byte[])(inValues[1]));
            return this.BeginUpgradeFirmware(DeviceIPAddress, buffer, callback, asyncState);
        }

        private object[] OnEndUpgradeFirmware(System.IAsyncResult result)
        {
            bool retVal = this.EndUpgradeFirmware(result);
            return new object[] {
                retVal};
        }

        private void OnUpgradeFirmwareCompleted(object state)
        {
            if ((this.UpgradeFirmwareCompleted != null))
            {
                InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs e = ((InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs)(state));
                this.UpgradeFirmwareCompleted(this, new UpgradeFirmwareCompletedEventArgs(e.Results, e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.UserState));
            }
        }

        public void UpgradeFirmwareAsync(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer)
        {
            this.UpgradeFirmwareAsync(DeviceIPAddress, buffer, null);
        }

        public void UpgradeFirmwareAsync(string DeviceIPAddress, byte[] buffer, object userState)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((this.onBeginUpgradeFirmwareDelegate == null))
                {
                    this.onBeginUpgradeFirmwareDelegate = new BeginOperationDelegate(this.OnBeginUpgradeFirmware);
                }
                if ((this.onEndUpgradeFirmwareDelegate == null))
                {
                    this.onEndUpgradeFirmwareDelegate = new EndOperationDelegate(this.OnEndUpgradeFirmware);
                }
                if ((this.onUpgradeFirmwareCompletedDelegate == null))
                {
                    this.onUpgradeFirmwareCompletedDelegate = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnUpgradeFirmwareCompleted);
                }
                base.InvokeAsync(this.onBeginUpgradeFirmwareDelegate, new object[] {
                    DeviceIPAddress,
                    buffer}, this.onEndUpgradeFirmwareDelegate, this.onUpgradeFirmwareCompletedDelegate, userState);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Taking a wild guess here: could it be that you added the Name or Namespace to your ServiceContract, and did not re-compile both your server and the client? Note that both have to be recompiled for this to work: if you just re-compile the server, you'll get the error you quoted. Make sure the client project has the correct interface, including all attributes.

Comment: I think you need to use IFirmwareUpgrade 
m_UITCPHost.AddServiceEndpoint( 
    typeof(**IUpdator**), 
    binding, 
    "UpdatorWCFService");